# How to multiply out brackets when they contain vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Little confused on the rules here, obviously if I treat it as a vector and its transpose I can compute this if I knew each vector entry but I am keen to know the general rule for any vector:

$(\mathbf x - \mathbf y)(\mathbf x - \mathbf y)^T$

How does it relate to $(x-y)(x-y) = x^2 - 2xy + y^2 $

Thanks for your help

Comment: Dot product $(\mathbf x-\mathbf y)\cdot (\mathbf x-\mathbf y)=\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf x-\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y -\mathbf  y\cdot \mathbf x +\mathbf  y\cdot \mathbf y$

Comment: Are these row vectors or column vectors? Is $\mathbf a\mathbf b^T$ an inner product or an outer(/tensor) product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT/CAVEAT: I am interpreting the vectors as row vectors. Please see the other answer for interpreting the vectors as column vectors.

You're correct that you should treat it as the vector and its transpose. This is called an "inner product", or a "dot product". In the trivial case that the vectors are both scalars, it reduces to the formula you said. Otherwise, it becomes $$x x^T -xy^T - yx^T + yy^T$$

$$=|x|^2 - 2 x\cdot y + |y|^2$$

Comment: So is it just taking the dot product of each element within the brackets? If this was the case it is much simpler than I imagined

Comment: You're correct. Technically, you can also think of it as just a general matrix multiplication. You use the distributive rules of matrix multiplication to expand the brackets, to get my first line above. Then, you can revert to thinking in terms of dot products, because all terms are, in fact, scalars. In particular, this means $xy^T=yx^T$.

Comment: seems like you are turning a matrix in a scalar: $xx^T$ is a matrix

Comment: Amazing, thank you for explaining

Comment: @LinAlg - They may be using row vectors instead of column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

To see why removing brackets is a bit different, you can remove them step by step:
$$(\mathbf x - \mathbf y)(\mathbf x - \mathbf y)^T = \mathbf x (\mathbf x - \mathbf y)^T - \mathbf y(\mathbf x - \mathbf y)^T = \mathbf x \mathbf x^T - \mathbf x\mathbf y^T - \mathbf y\mathbf x^T - \mathbf y \mathbf y^T$$
The result cannot be simplified any further, because unlike the scalar case, $\mathbf x\mathbf y^T \neq \mathbf y\mathbf x^T$

Comment: Ah okay, This is interpreting the vectors as column vectors. @InvestingScientist next time you should specify if your vectors are column or row vectors. This type of product is called an “outer product”.

Comment: If $x,y$ are row vectors, they do commute.  For general matrices, $x^Ty = (y^Tx)^T$, and hence if $x^Ty$ is not symmetric, they do not commute.